# How to create make file for template library in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, makefile

I am new to makefile concept and I Having [this](https://github.com/srilakshmikanthan-p/artlib) template library how can i create makefile to install this library on system, can i create makefile for template library.

Source code Folder structure(omitted some files):

```
artlib - c++
 |
 |--- include 
 |      |
 |      |--- artlib.hpp
 |
 |--- source
        |
        |---- anixt
        |       |
        |       |--- anixt_config.hpp
        |       |--- anixt_font.hpp
        |       |--- anixt_style.hpp
        |       |--- basic_anixt.hpp
        |
        |---- runeape
                |
                |--- basic_runeape.hpp
                |--- runeape_config.hpp
                |--- runeape_gallery.hpp
                |--- runeape_style.hpp

 |-------- third_party/json/json.hpp
```

Now, How to install this files and artlib.hpp file includes all other file and have some type alias and some functions. I am currently build test
code by -I option in g++ and include artlib.hpp in source file

All suggestions are welcome,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to install this library *without* Make?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Not completely but in linux i place the library in folder usr/local/include

Comment: You can write a makefile to do *that,* but in general you can't do anything with Make until you know how to do it without Make.

Comment: can you give some reference, because i did not know completely to install if it is single file i will easilly put the file in that folder but it has more, do i need put all files in that folder or i can create sub folder and does compiler will search in all sub folder ?

Comment: and makefile is only for linux or it is supported by windows ?

Comment: You can use CMake, to generate Makefiles. Although you may have to learn how to use it!

Comment: You can use Make on Windows. As for what installing the library entails, I don't know, perhaps you could read the `README`, or look at the `#include` statements, or ask the author, or experiment.

Comment: sorry it is my repo so why i asked this question i am completly new to makefile concept.

Comment: `make` can do this job, but if all you want to do is copy header files into the right spot then a plain shell script would probably be easier.  Such a task does not rely on any of the abilities that make `make` more powerful than a script, but you still pay a premium for setting it up in makefile format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a makefile to install a file `template.h` into `/usr/local/include`:

```
FILES := template.h
DESTDIR := /usr/local/include


INSTALLEDFILES := $(addprefix $(DESTDIR)/,$(FILES))

all: $(INSTALLEDFILES)

$(DESTDIR)/%: %
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        cp $< $@
```

Since you've not given us any actual details about what you want to do, that's about all we can say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you see updated question does this details is enough ?

Comment: I think my makefile here should be a sufficient starting point for you to implement what you want to implement.  StackOverflow isn't intended to be a site for people to implement full solutions for you for free: it's supposed to be a site where if you tried to figure something out for yourself and you have a specific problem you can ask a specific question about that problem and get some assistance.  If you don't understand some aspect of the sample I provided you can check the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html or ask a question about that thing.